# Scanning multiple numbers into one document

Tags: image-processing, ocr

I've got a lot of printed documents with a 12 digit number on the top right corners. What is the fastest way to scan those numbers into a single document each number on a new row using application or device. Any other solution to the issue would be much appreciated.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Those are printed documents in a large quantity so scanning them into PDFs would take a long time. If I had PDFs I could use Adobe DC reader. What I need is a software on a pc with webcam or on a smartphone or a QR or Barcode reader-like device that will just instantly scan what it sees into a document

Comment: Any sample document to show? You can hidden the info there except the numbers region. OpenCV and Tesseract can do the job with a properly mounted webcam as the video scanner.

Comment: Not an endorsement, just a suggestion http://www.irislink.com/EN-GB/c973/IRISPen-Executive-7---Pen-scanner.aspx

Comment: @thewaywewere here's a [sample](https://1drv.ms/i/s!Alh9v6ciuCBFtDoVcsr9yJkf68H4)

Comment: Thank you everyone for answers and suggestions. I've bought the device @MarkSetchell suggested that's exactly what I needed. There seems to be no way in this forum to mark comment as the correct answer so Mark if you please rewrite your comment as an answer I could mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the document sample, the possible solution is to use `Python` with `OpenCV`, or `pallow`,  and `tesseract` to implement a number scanning application.

1. Use a webcam to video the document and capture a frame image.
2. Crop the region of interest, i.e. the top-right area with the 12-digit number only.
3. Pass the cropped image for OCR.
4. Append the scanned number to a file.

Hope this help.